# How to declare a 2d array of size 500 x 500 in c language?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, size

I'm trying to declare a 2d array of 500 x 500 in c. Everytime do it, it throws compile time error stating "array size too long". How do i get around this problem.?? 
the compiler used is turbo C++ on windows 8.1

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[500][500];
void main()
{

printf("\nEnter the size of array:\n");
scanf("%d%d", &m,&n);
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        a[i][j]=0;
}
```

Comment: `int array[500][500]`? But be careful if declaring it as a local variable, as it will fill almost all of the stack on certain systems (and more that the available stack on other systems).

Comment: yup i did it and it threw a compile time error..

Comment: It works on GCC 4.6+ and Clang 3.0+. Your problem is that you are using a long outdated compiler straight from the '90s. Unless you have a compelling reason to use TurboC++, **please** download a decent C++ compiler. GCC, Clang, they are all free. There are also nice IDEs for true beginners like CodeBlocks and DevC++.

Comment: Your loop is redundant. That array already contains 0s.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`

Comment: And `int` variables should be declared. But neither the redundant loop or the `void main()` are the real issues here. Problem is that TurboC++ should not be used in 21st century period...

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of handling multi-dimensional arrays. The simplest is to just declare it as an array of arrays:

```
int array[X][Y];
```

However like I said in my comment this might cause stack-overflow if declared as a *local* variable. It's no problem if it's a global variable (unless the total size is to big to fit in the (virtual) memory of your system).

Another way might be to declare it as an array of pointers to whatever type is needed, and then allocate the "second" dimension in a loop:

```
int *array[X];
for (size_t i = 0; i < X; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * Y);
```

The third alternative, if `X` in my examples is still too big, is to use a pointer to a pointer to the type:

```
int **array;
array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * X);
for (size_t i = 0; i < X; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * Y);
```

***Note:*** When allocating memory dynamically with e.g. `malloc`, you need to `free` the memory once you are done with it.

Comment: I tried  declaring it as a global variable, but the error remains the same.. :(

Comment: @ShubhamSaini What system are you building for? Which compiler are you using? And more importantly, what *type* is the array-of-arrays using? Please edit your question to include that information, preferably showing the actual declaration.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg see comments on my answer, the OP is using TurboC++. I guess they never complied with any standard whatsoever, I am really sorry OP :(

Answer (score 0):

if the array is big, you should allocate it on heap, using for example `malloc()` function. compiler throws that error because of limited size of stack frame. 
i would do it in following way:

- allocate memory for an array[500] of pointers to int
- then, for every pointer in that array, allocate memory for array[500] of ints and assign current pointer to allocated array of ints;

here's a little program that fills array[500][500] with numbers from 0 to 249999. watch out for the output:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int* array[500];
    int rows, cols, num = 0;
    for (rows = 0; rows < 500; rows++) {
        array[rows] = malloc(500* sizeof(int));
        for (cols = 0; cols < 500; cols++) {
            array[rows][cols] = num;
            num++;
        }

    }
    for (rows = 0; rows < 500; rows++) {
        for (cols = 0; cols < 500; cols++) {
            printf("%d\n",array[rows][cols]);
        }
        free(array[rows]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a 500x500 matrix of `int` as a local variable, like in:

```
void somefunction() {
    int myarray[500][500];
    // ...
}
```

you are asking for 1MB of the stack (assuming `sizeof (int) == 4`, which is usual on x86). Stack size is limited to 1MiB by default on most compilers for a good reasons: detecting a possible infinite recursion. In fact, the stack reaching its 1MiB limit is quite unusual, so I advice against changing the default.

You have two possibilities:

1. allocate it on the heap using `int* myarray = malloc(500 * 500 * sizeof (int));`. Remember to call `free(myarray);` it when you are done!
2. declare the array as a global variable (don't do it unless you have a strong reason to do so).

Comment: The global thing didn't work .. know any reason why ??

Comment: What compiler and flags are you using? What is the exact error message? It works on GCC and Clang on Linux.

Comment: @ShubhamSaini `static int myarray[500][500];`

Comment: I'm using trubo c++. Exact error message: Array size too large.

Comment: TurboC++ in 21st century?? Can you use another compiler? Or is it a forced choice?

Comment: @ShubhamSaini I know that Turbo C++ is common in certain schools in India, but it's so out of date that it's unfortunately no use to you once you leave school.  Remember that is was originally made for old MS-DOS with it's extremely (by today standards) limited segmented memory, where you can't really address more than 64 *kilo* bytes. I'm sorry, but learning to program C++ using Turbo C++ will only hinder you in your future career.

Comment: @ShubhamSaini Regarding your error, there's really nothing you can do, Turbo C++ simply can't be used with such large data,

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You're right to tell @ShubhamSaini about the limitation MS-DOS had. 64KB = 65536 bytes, and `int[500][500]` will take up `sizeof(int)*250000` bytes. Even without the multiplication, it is easy to see that `250000 > 65536`. It just doesn't work at all.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm asked to perform Gcd of two matrix generated by random numbers. It works fine for equal matrix. now there may occur a situation when  
I've two matrices of different order, say one is of 10 x 7 and other is 9 x 3, i need to equalize second order(i.e 9 x 3 to 10 x 7) so that i can perform operations.. Any suggestion on how to get around this situation.. please help me out and yup i've changed my compiler thanks for suggestion..

Comment: @ShubhamSaini I guess that should be a new question. Put some effort into solving the problem, see where you are stuck, do research on the Internet and if everything else fails, ask another question on SO.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Do you think i haven't tried any of it ? :p And SO is not allowing me to ask this question dear !!

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, but if you are not allowed to ask questions [there might be a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997).